# django, ManyToManyField in Abstract Class Model, is it impossible?

Tags: django

**CODE:**

```
class Basemodel(models.Model):
    set = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="setset_set", symmetrical=False, through="Follow")
    class Meta :
        abstract = True


class Post_1(Basemodel):
    post1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Post_2(Basemodel):
    post2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="who_is_allowing",)
    followee = models.ForeignKey(Basemodel, related_name="who_is_allowed",)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s follows %s at %s" %(self.follower, self.followee, self.updated_at)
```

In that codes, I wanna make a ManyToManyField in abstract class.

**So i want to make a user can follow Post_1 or Post_2, whatever kind of post it is.**

**And more, i want to check how it goes on `Follow Class`, which is used in `Basemodel` - `set = models.ManyToManyField` - `through` kwargs**

Is there no way to make it possible?

Comment: The reason that this approach won't work is that the `followee` field has to point to a specific database table. `Basemodel`, since it's abstract, doesn't have its own table. In each row of the `Follow` table, `followee` has to refer to either `Post_1` or `Post_2`, but it currently has no way of knowing which one. The simplest approach may be to get rid of the abstract `Basemodel` and keep all the posts in one table with a `post_type` field. A lot depends on how different the post types are, whether you may eventually have addiional types, and exactly what you're trying to accomplish.